# Indentation after itemize enviroment inside \newtheorem enviroment

Tags: amsmath, itemize

I can't figure out how to not indent some "regular text" after an itemize enviroment, which is inside a \newtheorem enviroment. Basically I'm trying to create a new paragraph, containing the rest of the chapter, after the two theorems I wrote. This is my main.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend} Nel caso volessi aumentare la dimensione dei caratteri globalmente.
    \setboolean{@twoside}{false}

    %\doublespacing %nel caso volessi aumentare di due linee lo spacing
    \onehalfspacing
    \begin{document}

    \includepdf[pages=-, offset=0cm 4cm]{frontespizio.pdf}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty} %clears head and foot
    \vspace*{15cm} %adjust spacing as you like
    \begin{center}  
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
        \vrule height1cm width 0pt depth0pt
        \emph{A tutti coloro \\che hanno reso questo possibile.}
        \vrule height1cm width 0pt depth0pt
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{center}
    \vfill

    \mainmatter
    \include{./TeX_files/intro}
    \include{./TeX_files/Chapter1/chapter01}

    \backmatter
    % bibliography, glossary and index would go here.

    \end{document}
```

This is the chapter where the problem arises (see the `%TODO` in the following code)

```
\chapter{Presentazione del modello}
Tuttavia, resta da determinare la "giusta" trasformazione di stato $T(x)$. A tal fine si introducono, brevemente, alcuni importanti strumenti matematici.

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{Frobenius}{Teorema di Frobenius}
\begin{Frobenius}
    Sia $\left\lbrace v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{n}\right\rbrace$ un insieme di campi vettoriali linearmente indipendenti. L'insieme è completamente integrabile se, e solo se, esso è involutivo.
\end{Frobenius}

\newtheorem*{FondTheorem}{Teorema}
\begin{FondTheorem}
    Il sistema non lineare
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{cases}
        &\dot{x} = f(x) + g(x)u\\
        &y=h(x)
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
    dove $f$ e $g$ sono campi vettoriali di classe $C^{\infty}$, si dice input-state linearizzabile se, e solo se, esiste una regione $\Omega$ tale che:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item i campi vettoriali $\left\lbrace g,ad_{f} \; g, \dots, ad_{f}^{n-1} \; g\right\rbrace$ sono linearmente indipendenti in $\Omega$
        \item l'insieme $\left\lbrace g,ad_{f} \; g, \dots, ad_{f}^{n-2} \; g\right\rbrace$ è involutivo
    \end{itemize}
\end{FondTheorem}

%TODO the following text shouldn't be aligned with the itemize enviroment, but it should be indented like a regular paragraph text

In base ai risultati visti è possibile ricavare una procedura per effettuare la input-state linearization, del sistema non lineare in esame, riassumibile nei seguenti passi:
\begin{itemize}
    \item ricavare i campi vettoriali:
    \begin{align*}          
        & \left\lbrace g,ad_{f} \; g, \dots, ad_{f}^{n-1} \; g\right\rbrace \label{eq:one} \tag{i}\\
        & \left\lbrace g,ad_{f} \; g, \dots, ad_{f}^{n-2} \; g\right\rbrace \label{eq:two} \tag{{ii}}\\
    \end{align*}
    \item ...

\end{itemize} %the following text is correctly aligned
Tornando al modello...
```

This is what I get
[image: this is what I get]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you make yours a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. I mean that you should trim your code and leave only the part that causes the problem.

Comment: To suppress indentation of a paragraph just add a `\noindent` infront of it.

Comment: @Moriambar Thanks for answering. Yeah I already did that. I mean, I used the amount of code I thought was right.
@Skillmon Unfortunately `\noindent` removes the indentation completely and it only works for one line. I'd like to keep writing my chapter with the intendation I used before the two theorems (sorry if my explanation is a bit clumsy)

Comment: If you're using `\newtheorem*{something}{Teorema}` before any statement, don't: just use `\newtheorem(Theorem}{Teorema}` once and for all in the preamble.

Comment: @Nico769 it is really not clear what you mean with _the indentation I used before the two theorems_ LaTeX will use the correct indentation of paragraphs and whatnot.

Comment: Also you should `\include[T1]{fontenc}` in addition to `inputenc`.

Comment: @Moriambar I'd like "In base ai risultati.." to be aligned with "Tuttavia, resta da determinare.." I've added a picture showing my problem.

Comment: @Skillmon done that but the text doesn't seem as "smooth" as before

Comment: @egreg thanks, will do. I'm still learning the package as I write the thesis..

Comment: For smoother text also use `\include{lmodern}` (if you use the default Computer Modern font, this looks very close to it).

Comment: @Skillmon Ok, now it seems better. Yes, I think I'm using Computer Modern font since it should be the one shipped with the "Book" class

Comment: @Nico769 see my updated answr below

Answer (score 1):

If you have no `itemize` in the theorem, the text will be indented in the same way: the `itemize` has no relevance here. I added some text between the two theorem statements in order to show this.

Don't worry! The indent is right! Maybe you could avoid ending a statement with a list.

<sub>My impression is that the second statement is a definition, rather than a theorem, but you're the judge.</sub>

I made some fixes to your code: please, have a look at them. In particular,

1. there's no need to do `\newtheorem*` before every theorem;
2. TeX would be a very poor system if one had to type `\left\lbrace` and `\right\rbrace` for every set denotation;
3. I believe to have used `\;` just a handful of times in my life (well maybe some more, but just to give you an idea) and I've been using TeX/LaTeX since 1988; what you need is to define an operator, so the spacing will be automatic;
4. quotes should be ``` `` ``` and `''`, never `"`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <--- don't forget
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % <--- don't forget titles
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend} % 12pt is the size for primary school textbooks
%\setboolean{@twoside}{false} % NO! Set the oneside option, if really needed

%\doublespacing %nel caso volessi aumentare di due linee lo spacing
\onehalfspacing

\DeclareMathOperator{\ad}{ad}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{unnumberedtheorem}{\unnumberedtheoremname}
\providecommand{\unnumberedtheoremname}{}
\newenvironment{Teorema}[1][Teorema]
  {\renewcommand{\unnumberedtheoremname}{#1}\unnumberedtheorem}
  {\endunnumberedtheorem}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Presentazione del modello}
Tuttavia, resta da determinare la ``giusta'' trasformazione di stato $T(x)$. 
A tal fine si introducono, brevemente, alcuni importanti strumenti matematici.

\begin{Teorema}[Teorema di Frobenius]
Sia $\{v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{n}\}$ un insieme di campi vettoriali linearmente 
indipendenti. L'insieme è completamente integrabile se, e solo se, esso è involutivo.
\end{Teorema}

Qui aggiungo un testo per dimostrare come il rientro sia presente indipendentemente
da eventuali \texttt{itemize} nell'enunciato.

\begin{Teorema}
Il sistema non lineare
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{cases}
  \dot{x} = f(x) + g(x)u\\
  y=h(x)
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
dove $f$ e $g$ sono campi vettoriali di classe $C^{\infty}$, si dice 
input-state linearizzabile se, e solo se, esiste una regione $\Omega$ tale che:
\begin{itemize}
  \item i campi vettoriali $\{ g,\ad_{f} g, \dots, \ad_{f}^{n-1} g \}$ sono
        linearmente indipendenti in $\Omega$;
  \item l'insieme $\{ g,\ad_{f} g, \dots, \ad_{f}^{n-2} g \}$ è involutivo.
\end{itemize}
\end{Teorema}

In base ai risultati visti è possibile ricavare una procedura per effettuare 
la input-state linearization, del sistema non lineare in esame, riassumibile 
nei seguenti passi:
\begin{itemize}
  \item ricavare i campi vettoriali:
  \begin{align*}          
  & \{ g,\ad_{f} g, \dots, \ad_{f}^{n-1} g \} \label{eq:one} \tag{i}\\
  & \{ g,\ad_{f} g, \dots, \ad_{f}^{n-2} g \} \label{eq:two} \tag{{ii}}
  \end{align*}
  \item ...
  \item ...
\end{itemize}
Tornando al modello...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the corrections! I changed my code accordingly. On the book I'm using as reference, the second statement is denoted as a theorem, that's why I marked it as such. In your code "In base ai.." is still vertically aligned as if it was an item of itemize; I'd like "In base ai" as if it was a new paragraph, because I don't want to keep writing about theorems. Hope I shed some light

Comment: @Nico769 It *is* a new paragraph, as shown by the indentation. You may decide you want a different indent for itemized lists: see the `enumitem` package documentation.

Comment: I understand. Will do. I guess my theorems formatting is poor. I'm sure there's a better way to add n-theorems and then continue with the rest of the chapter.

Answer (score 0):

The text is aligned correctly as far as I can tell. Since the theorem is a self-contained "paragraph-like" environment, when you type text under it, it starts a new paragraph, giving the indentation.

If you want to suppress it simply give `\noindent` before your text, i.e.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend} Nel caso volessi aumentare la dimensione dei caratteri globalmente.
    \setboolean{@twoside}{false}

    %\doublespacing %nel caso volessi aumentare di due linee lo spacing
    \onehalfspacing
        \newtheorem*{FondTheorem}{Teorema}
    \begin{document}
\chapter{Presentazione del modello}
Tuttavia, resta da determinare la "giusta" trasformazione di stato $T(x)$. A tal fine si introducono, brevemente, alcuni importanti strumenti matematici.

\begin{FondTheorem}
    Il sistema non lineare
    \begin{equation*}
        \begin{cases}
        &\dot{x} = f(x) + g(x)u\\
        &y=h(x)
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
    dove $f$ e $g$ sono campi vettoriali di classe $C^{\infty}$, si dice input-state linearizzabile se, e solo se, esiste una regione $\Omega$ tale che:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item i campi vettoriali $\left\lbrace g,ad_{f} \; g, \dots, ad_{f}^{n-1} \; g\right\rbrace$ sono linearmente indipendenti in $\Omega$
        \item l'insieme $\left\lbrace g,ad_{f} \; g, \dots, ad_{f}^{n-2} \; g\right\rbrace$ è involutivo
    \end{itemize}
\end{FondTheorem}

\noindent In base ai risultati visti è possibile ricavare una procedura per effettuare la input-state linearization, del sistema non lineare in esame, riassumibile nei seguenti passi:
\end{document}
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: `\noindent` seems to work now. Maybe I should avoid ending a statement with a list in the future, since it gives the illusion of bad formatting.. Thanks!